# Fast implementation for neighbourhoods in numpy tensor

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3-tensor `A` in numpy and an index `(i,j,k)`. I need to put in a single (possibly numpy) array `arr` the linear index of the 'neighborhoods' of `(i,j,k)`, (i.e., the elements `(i+i1, j+j1, k+k1)`, where `i1, j1, k2 = -1, 0, 1`). I need to do this for every index `(i,j,k)` of `A`, so my question is, there is a short and fast way to do this?

A toy example:

```
n = 10
dim = (10, 10, 10)
i, j, k = (2, 3, 4)
res = []
pm = [-1, 0, 1]
for i1 in range(3):
    for j1 in range(3):
        for k1 in range(3):
            # ravel_multi_index transforms a multi-index (i,j,k) to the corresponding linear index of a tensor of shape "dim"
            res.append(np.ravel_multi_index((i + pm[i1], j + pm[j1], k + pm[k1]), dim))
#print...
[123, 124, 125, 133, 134, 135, 143, 144, 145, 223, 224, 225, 233, 234, 235, 243, 244, 245, 323, 324, 325, 333, 334, 335, 343, 344, 345]
```

There are 27 neighborhoods.

The boundary index has fewer neighborhoods: for example, the coordinate (0, 0, 0) has 8 neighborhoods.

As solution, I was thinking in some "traslation" of the neighborhoods to one fixed, but this rapidly become cumbersome.

Comment: may you create a toy example and expected output?

Comment: .. What's `pm`?

Comment: @Divakar uuups, I overwrite it when I pasted the code

Comment: What are you doing with the indices afterwards? There might be a better solution than collecting all the indices for such a simple 3x3x3 neighbourhood.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. You just generate the `vertices` array once and let broadcasting do the rest. `vertices` gives all 27 possibilities required to add to an index and get all its neighbors.

```
ijk = np.array([2, 3, 4]) # an example point 
dim = (10, 10, 10) # dimensions 

pts = np.stack(([-1,0,1],)*3,0)
vertices = (np.array(np.meshgrid(*pts)).T).reshape(3**3,3) # a 27x3 array
# the vertices are the points to add to ijk to get all neighbors 

n = (vertices + ijk).T # neighbors 
n = n.T[((n[0]>=0)&(n[0]<dim[0])
         &(n[1]>=0)&(n[1]<dim[1])
          &(n[2]>=0)&(n[2]<dim[2]))] # out of bounds elements filtered
```

This returns

```
>>> n
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 3, 3],
       [1, 4, 3],
       [2, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 3],
       [2, 4, 3],
       [3, 2, 3],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [3, 4, 3],
       [1, 2, 4],
       [1, 3, 4],
       [1, 4, 4],
       [2, 2, 4],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [2, 4, 4],
       [3, 2, 4],
       [3, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 4],
       [1, 2, 5],
       [1, 3, 5],
       [1, 4, 5],
       [2, 2, 5],
       [2, 3, 5],
       [2, 4, 5],
       [3, 2, 5],
       [3, 3, 5],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

You can force this into your example output with

```
sorted([int(''.join(x)) for x in n.astype('str')])
```

Which returns

```
 [123,
 124,
 125,
 133,
 134,
 135,
 143,
 144,
 145,
 223,
 224,
 225,
 233,
 234,
 235,
 243,
 244,
 245,
 323,
 324,
 325,
 333,
 334,
 335,
 343,
 344,
 345]
```